# USB RAW (BULK) VISA Read/Write inside loop too slow?

Tags: usb, labview, visa

I have a custom USB device containing an ADC whose sampled data I want to receive in LabVIEW. The data rate is 16.384 MBit/s with block sizes of 1024 Bytes every 500 us. A tiny C++ application I built for receiving the data (based on WinUSB driver) is working without any problems.

For setting up the USB communication in LabVIEW I followed this article: https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA03q000000x1qzCAA

Basically, the communication is working and I can receive some of the data. However, every few seconds packages are lost and in the Windows 10 device manager I can see that the device is disconnected and directly reconnected again. Is it possible that LabVIEW is not able to perform a USB read/write procedure every 500 us? Can I improve my LabVIEW program somehow (I am new to LabVIEW)?

Thank you very much for your help/your ideas!

[image: Block diagram]

Comment: 500 us - is too much not for LabVIEW itself, but for Windows. In order to keep such reading rate, you need to consider using Real-Time system; because on Windows you could reach 1 ms resolution just. But overall, there is no need to read so fast, b/c I believe that your usb device supports buffering - so you could read, let's say, each 1 second bigger chunk of data, which is the common practice. So add delay into reading while loop (I'd suggest 500 - 1000 ms), and try like that.

Comment: In almost 8 years of working with LabVIEW, I have nearly universally found USB devices to be the least reliable of all. I'd recommend you ditch USB altogether, honestly. Pretty much anything else is better.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help! I solved the problem by adjusting the USB device's firmware: Instead of sending 1024 bytes each 500 us, 20480 bytes are transferred every 10 ms now. Thanks again!

Comment: This sounds very strange. A bulk endpoint is a stream protocol with flow control. It has no fixed timing and no fixed message size. The host will determine if and when it is ready to receive data. So the device should continuously add samples to a buffer and transmit data whenever the host asks for it and data is available. The buffer should be sized to absorb the data for the longest stalling (of LabVIEW in your case). Fixed timings do not work with bulk endpoints. It sounds as if you have decreased the likelihood of lost data but not addressed the underlying problem.